# In Clion IDE, running OpenCV code in WSL2 throws (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'

Tags: c++, opencv, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clion

I try to run a compiled openCV program in clion, work with ubuntu20 wsl2.
On WSL, it compiles correctly and runs correctly.
But , when running this target on clion, I got the following error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  OpenCV(4.6.0) /mnt/c/Users/shade/Downloads/opencv-4.6.0/opencv-4.6.0/modules/highgui/src/window_gtk.cpp:635: error: (-2:Unspecified error) Can't initialize GTK backend in function 'cvInitSystem'

Process finished with exit code 6
```

I found that when I run follw commad on powershell, get same error.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wsl.exe --distribution Ubuntu-20.04 -u root --exec /bin/bash -c "cd '/mnt/c/Users/shade/Documents/GitHub/SFND-master/3_Camera/04_Tracking Image Features/cornerness_harris/cmake-build-debug-wsl' && '/mnt/c/Users/shade/Documents/GitHub/SFND-master/3_Camera/04_Tracking Image Features/cornerness_harris/cmake-build-debug-wsl/cornerness_harris'"
```

How can I make clion run the target with wsl terminal directly？

Comment: ***Can't initialize GTK backend in function*** I think the problem is more WSL than CLion.

Comment: Here is an old question about running GTK on WSL (not sure if it still applies for you): [https://askubuntu.com/questions/897846/cant-run-gtk-on-wsl-display-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897846/cant-run-gtk-on-wsl-display-error)

Comment: Here is a Microsoft document: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps) that states ***You will need to be on Windows 11 Build 22000 or later to access this feature.***

Comment: post an answer :)

Comment: I didn't answer for a few reasons. 1) I just goggled to get the links and 2) I was not sure of what exact OS the OP was using and if they had a terminal. I believe even on an older OS you can use MobaXTerm or similar and get this to work in WSL although I have not tested that often.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but I don't think the problem is WSL. Beacause it work on WSL terminal, I use X11 for the GUI.

Comment: why are you even doing this in WSL? opencv prefers to run natively.

Comment: I think you are right !!!But I can run Clion in wsl. It totally solve my problem